# Cauchy surface for sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

If we have a Lorentzian manifold $\mathbb{R} \times S^n$ with metric $g= -dt^2 + ds^n$ where $ds^n$ is just the standard round metric for spheres. Does this manifold have a Cauchy surface, i.e. is it globally hyperbolic? And if so what is the Cauchy surface?
Basically that would mean that the Cauchy surface is homeomorphic to $S^n$. I think that means that there exists no Cauchy surface but I am not sure.

Comment: Isn't $\{t\}\times \mathbb S^n$ (with $t\in \mathbb R$ fixed) a Cauchy surface ?

Comment: More generally, a spacetime $(\Bbb R\times M, -{\rm d}t^2 \oplus g)$ is globally hyperbolic if and only if $(M,g)$ is a complete Riemannian manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every $\{t\}\times \mathbb S^n$ with $t\in \mathbb R$ fixed is a Cauchy surface : let $\gamma: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R\times \mathbb S^n$ be a smooth time-like curve. Write $\gamma(\lambda)= (t(\lambda),x(\lambda))$.

Then :
$$ \left[\text dt (\dot \gamma)\right]^2 > [\text ds(\dot\gamma)]^2 \tag{1}$$
so in particular $\text dt(\dot \gamma) = \frac{\text dt}{\text d\lambda}  \neq 0$. Therefore, $t(\lambda):\mathbb R\to t(\mathbb R) = (a,b)$ is a diffeomorphism and we can consider the function $x(t): (a,b)\to \mathbb S^n$. Equation $(1)$ gives us :
$$\left\|\frac{\text dx}{\text dt}\right\|<1$$

and we can extend $x(t)$ to a map $\mathbb R \to\mathbb S^n$, which meets every $\{t\}\times \mathbb S^n$.

*Remark* : This works for every space-time of the form $\mathbb R\times S$ metric $-\text dt^2 + \text ds^2$ where $(S,\text ds^2)$ is a complete Riemaniann manifold.

Comment: I have one question to your proof concerning equation (1). In the definitions of Cauchy surface I used the Lorentzian manifold had sign convention $[+,-,...,-]$. Now in this case the sign convention is the complementary. Doesn't that then mean that time-like here is $g(v,v)>0$ with this convention?

Comment: In OP, you used $(-,+,\ldots,+)$. Time-like means the time component is larger. With the convention we both used above, time-like is $g(v,v) <0$. With the opposite convention, it is $g(v,v)>0$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. My confusion why I thought it has no Cauchy surface mainly was because I thought time-like with my convention is $g(v,v)>0$. But it is a nice proof you provided. Thank you